# How to make Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I searched lot, but cant get perfect solution for below question.

I have a following code to get string values from one line of string by making regex and creating pattern object and matching 
in string with Matcher.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("product val='321ddfgsagsdf' find way");
    list.add("product val='781ertergdfv' find way");
    list.add("product val='96puil$hjgh&fgh' find way"); //Here special characters in string
    list.add("product val='25errgfgsagsdf' find way");
    list.add("product val='562qweddfgsagsdf' find way");

    for (String string : list) {
        Pattern myPat = Pattern.compile(" val='(.*?)'", 2);
        Matcher m = myPat.matcher(string);
        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1));
        }       }
}
```

Here I am able to get values for ref, inside the single quotes.

But, third value is having "$" and "&" in ref value, which I don't want to process it in pattern.

I know it is possible by checking string, if string contains special chars and avoid it. But, I want to make it using regex, as my app is checking very much bigger strings.

Is there any way to avoid this special characters in java regex?

Comment: What is a "special chars" in your case? Does a space qualify? Puctuation?

Comment: Are you sure your code works? You do not even run the matcher.

Comment: @Lucero, space and Punctuation are not allowed,

Comment: Yes, but your regex says `val` and there is no `val` in the input. There is `ref`. Please make sure you post what you really have, or we'll be unable to help quickly and efficiently. If you want to follow your blacklisting approach try `Pattern myPat = Pattern.compile(" ref='([^\\s\\p{P}\\p{S}]+)'");`. However, as I thought initially, `Pattern myPat = Pattern.compile(" ref='(\\w+)'");` should work, too.

Comment: Isn't the answer below enough? It was the solution in my first removed comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can restrict the match like this (that would be alphanumeric for instance, but you can also use a character class `[0-9a-z]` or so):

```
Pattern myPat = Pattern.compile(" val='(\\w+)'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: Code with this pattern doesn't compile: [http://ideone.com/mCswNx](http://ideone.com/mCswNx).

Comment: @DimaSan That's because the sample is missing a `import java.util.regex.*;` at the top - it has nothing to do with my answer.

Comment: Ok fine, can you pls help me for the following scenario? If I just want to avoid only "$" and "&", but need to allow all other characters.

Comment: @Clara Then you could use Use `" val='([^$&']+)'"` as pattern. This is very basic regex stuff, you should find what you need for instance here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ - Also, if your question is answered, please accept the answer which helped you.